# How to programmatically create a button to appear in separate view controller swift

Tags: swift, uibutton, viewcontroller

I created a function in `ViewController` one that creates a `UIButton`.

When I call the function in the same `ViewController`, in `ViewDidLoad`, it works fine.  But when I try calling the function with a button I created in a popover, I keep getting this

> Error "Thread1:EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=1, subcode=0x1002ce588)".

I realize this is a common Error but I can not seem to find a way around it.

Here is what I have.

```
class func addButtonToMainController()
{
    var button1: UIButton!
    button1 = UIButton(type: .System)
    button1.setTitle("placeholder", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button1.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    button1.center = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    button1.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)
    button1.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    button1.addTarget(MainViewController(), action: Selector("animateButtonPressed:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    MainViewController().view.addSubview(button1)
}
func animateButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject){
    print("animate")
}
```

here is where I call the function, from the popover viewcontroller.

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    MainViewController.addButtonToMainController()
}
```

The point here is to create a working button on the main view controller while in the popover. any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Are you sure `buttonPressed` is getting called? I used to get this error when I hadn't connected my `@IBAction` to the element in interface builder properly.

Comment: yeah, I tried it on a different button that I created to perform a simple action. the button worked fine until I added that function to it. same error.

Comment: is the `addButtonToMainController` method in the `mainViewController` or in the `popOver`?

Comment: the method is located in the mainviewcontroller.  which is where I am wanting the new button to be located

Comment: When you `addSubView(button1)` why are you not using `self.view.addSubview`?

Comment: one of the suggestions I read was to the function into a class so it can be accessed globally.  doing so made it a requirement to add MainViewController() in front of view.addSubview(button1).  if I put self, it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: If `self.view.addSubview(button1)` doesn't compile, then it doesn't sound like this method is being run on your viewController - It sounds like your reference to your MainViewController() is getting lost somewhere, you may need to provide a fuller example for people to be able to assist you.

Comment: How is your popover created? With a segue or in code?

Answer (score 0):

What you have isn't working because you are creating new instances of `MainViewController` every time you call `MainViewController`.  You need to make sure you are talking to the one and only `MainViewController` that was created by the Storyboard.

In order to call a function in another viewController, you need an instance of that viewController.  The best way to do that with a viewController that is presented as a popOver is to use delegation.

In my example below, I have used a segue to present the `SecondViewController`.  I have defined a protocol called `ButtonAdder` which simply describes a class that implements the method `addButton`.

Then, make sure `MainViewController` implements the `ButtonAdder` protocol by adding `ButtonAdder` to the `class` declaration line and providing the `addButton` method.

In `prepareForSegue`, add the instance of `MainViewController` (i.e. `self`) as the `delegate` of the `SecondViewController`.

In the `SecondViewController`, call `delegate?.addButton()` when you need the `MainViewController` to add its button.

Make sure the segue identifier is set to `"presentPopover"` in the *Attributes Inspector* for the code below to work.

---

**MainViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

protocol ButtonAdder: class {
    func addButton()
}

class MainViewController: UIViewController, ButtonAdder {

    func addButton() {
        var button1: UIButton!
        button1 = UIButton(type: .System)
        button1.setTitle("placeholder", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button1.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        button1.center = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        button1.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)
        button1.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        button1.addTarget(self, action: Selector("animateButtonPressed:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button1)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "presentPopover" {
            let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
            dvc.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func animateButtonPressed(button: UIButton) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

---

**SecondViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: ButtonAdder?

    @IBAction func doCall(sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.addButton()
    }

}
```